# Eclipse Indigo with Aptana Studio 3 - Code hinting doesn't work when Dojo libraries are local

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, dojo, aptana3

I've just setup Eclipse with Aptana Studio 3 and have been trying to get code completion / code hinting / autocomplete to work with mixed results.

I've followed the instructions here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support

What I have discovered through testing is that when you install the .sdocml file and nothing else in a new project, it works fine.

As soon as I add a local copy of Dojo into the project the code hinting no longer works correctly.

I tried excluding the directory from view with a filter but that excludes it from the server so you can't use it. I've also tried removing the Dojo folder from Indexing but that changes nothing either.

If I load Dojo from a CDN, like Google, then I can use code completion.

The issue is that Eclipse picks up a parsed reference to dojo instead of the one from the sdocml file.

The problem seems, so far, to be confined to typing 'dojo.' but 'dijit.' and 'dojox.' work okay, maybe because of the parent-child relationship between those sub-libraries, if I were to guess.

I don't know if this is an Aptana bug or an Eclipse bug, but either way, it's a problem.

Does anyone know how to prioritize the code hinting sources and / or exclude certain directories from being a hinting source? Or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance,
Ken

**Edit:** Now that I have more code in the test project hinting does not work at all for 'dojo.' but still works fine for 'dojox.' and 'dijit.'. Only native JS methods hinting is available as a subset of 'dojo.'